# Node js - How to a job in sequential order

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequential

Iam a node js beginner. I want to do some Job in Node js in a sequential order.

```
Fetch from DB -> Do some operation ->  export as excel -> Mail
```

As Node js async,Do I need to code like below?

```
function fetchDB();
function operation(results,callback);
function excel(result,callback());
function mail(result);

fetchDB(operation(results,excel(result,mail(result))));
```

is the above way is right? or any other good ways to achieve this?

Comment: Obviously your syntax is incorrect, but the spirit is there, though you'll want to look into Promises to make things a bit more palatable.

Comment: Use async.js node.js module (http://caolan.github.io/async/) and use series function

Comment: To get an understanding of what promises are - take a look at https://www.promisejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read into [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises). They allow you to run code immediately after asynchronous code returns. Also see [promisejs.org](https://www.promisejs.org/) as noted in the comments by @AnnaFohlmeister.

Promises are a more advanced (and cleaner) implementation of callbacks and can allow for more complex chaining of actions after asynchronous code finishes. Using callbacks you tend to run into what is called "callback hell" where you will have a ton of different actions nested into many callbacks and is not easy to write in a modular way (like changing out which operations do what after the end of which call).

As for your code it's correct using callbacks, though when defining `excel(result, callback())` remove `()` on the callback because that will most likely confuse node when it's initializing the functions. Also I'm assuming that your `excel` function makes another asynchronous call in it.